# How to create a loop where loop changes every post?

Tags: php, loop

How can I create a type of loop in WordPress where an image moves left or right for each post? I.e. first post image will be left, second post image will go right, third post image will go left, and so on...

[image]

Comment: Not really WordPress specific. What you need is a counter, modulus operator and variable class according to the result of the modulus, and then CSS which should be something like `float: right` or `float: left` according the class set via the result of the modulus

Comment: FYI, there is a tutorial for this, just can't remember where. I know this, because I searched for something similar when I started out. Just put some effort in and do some research, you'll find it. If I remember correctly, the tutorial was done on the twentyeleven theme, so `twentyeleven` would be great keyword to search for

Answer (score 1):

The PHP modulus operator gives you the remainder from dividing 2 numbers. The remainder from the division of any number by two is either 0 or 1, so we can use that to provide an "alternator". We use the `current_post` var as a counter, which is available in any `WP_Query` object:

```
while( have_posts() ){
    the_post();

    if( $wp_query->current_post % 2 ){
        echo 'right';
    } else {
        echo 'left';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much. Problem solved. Here is my code.

```
<section id="features">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'service',
            'posts_per_page' => 4
        );
        $service = new WP_Query($args);
        while ( $service->have_posts() ) : $service->the_post(); 
        ?>
            <?php if($service->current_post % 2) : ?>
             <div class="single-features" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"<?php post_class('my-class'); ?>>

                <div class="col-sm-5 wow fadeInLeft imagePosition" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 wow fadeInRight textPosition" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <P> <?php the_content(); ?></P>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>

             <div class="single-features">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 align-right wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <P><?php the_content(); ?></P>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- Do other stuff... -->

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
 <!--/#features-->
```